# Remove Background From RAW Images Using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, photography

I have two pictures -- for simplicity, let's say one contains a pot plant in a garden (let's call it `potplant.nef`), and the second contains the same scene, but minus the pot plant (i.e. just the background - let's call it `garden.nef`). I want to remove the background from the picture with the pot plant so that I just have the pot plant so I can lift and drop that into a different background.

I would like to this with ImageMagick.

Now I know there's various questions, answers here, and to different levels of success, but in this case, I took the photos as RAW (not PNG, not JPG, specifically to avoid some of the issues raised in the other questions). What's the *best* way of doing this?

Comment: You understand that you would need to have used a tripod for this and hope neither the camera nor anything else moved between the two frames and that the exposure settings and lighting were identical?

Comment: Further, you understand that the result will not be a NEF file as ImageMagick doesn't write raw files?

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#known_bgnd

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, I have a tripod and the same settings are used on both. In fact, I had it set to repeatedly take pictures so yes, they would be the same.

Comment: @MarkSetchell and yes to the second point. I have no issue with the output not being NEF coming out of ImageMagick.

Comment: Start by converting your RAW to JPG in some raw processing application. I assume you were in all-manual mode (so the camera didn't change its settings due to the plant). Doing that processing yourself (instead of in-camera), lets you ensure that the raw-processing app applies the very same settings for both pictures (which would not necessarily be true if this were the in-camera JPG). I assume you were using a contrasting background (because it this is just other green plants, software will have a hard time distinguishing the plant fro the background).